# Why Won't My Gradient Volume Work?

Tags: volumetrics

I'm trying to make a fog that is so thick you can hardly see through it at the bottom, and becoming invisible up top.  I've made this setup but for some reason my volume seems to be ignoring my gradient texture, which you can see should be correct in the first image.

What am I missing here?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iw9j15rx4nut2ct/GradientWhy.blend?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use the _UV_ socket of the _Texture Coordinate_ node, use either _Generated_ or _Object_. The _UV_ coordinates only hold surface information, so the inside value of the cube is some homogenous value overall.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes from the pics you have applied, used a Separate XYZ node instead of gradient. Hope this will help.
[image]

Comment: The trick here is not only that you used a _Separate XYZ_ node... but you are using the _Generated_ output of the _Texture Coordinate_ node. It would also work with the _Object_ output and there would be no need for a _Separate XYZ_. The problem with the original setup is using the _UV_ coordinates. I'm no expert, my guess is that the _UV_ coordinates only map the texture onto the surface and don't take the 3D volume into account so that the inside of the cube doesn't get the gradient and is always homogenous, whereas the _Generated_ and _Object_ outputs have values throughout the mesh.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that, I forgot to mention that part too, just realized it

Comment: It's okay, you mention you've done some changes. I just wanted to point that out because if someone thinks a _Separate XYZ_ would be the solution - it's not. If you still use _UV_ you will get a gradient on the surface as well, but still no gradient in the volume. As I said, the _Separate XYZ_ isn't the key to the problem, the gradient works just as fine if you switch to _Generated_ or _Object_. You only have to adjust the _Mapping_ node and _Color Ramp_ differently.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an answer @Wiseman I really appreciate your solution

Comment: Ahh, I completely overlooked the UV input.  Total head slap moment!  Thank you for clearing that up @GordonBrinkmann, if you would like to post your comment as an answer I will mark it accordingly.